# How to change a string into a discord id in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get a piece of code to work but it's constantly getting stuck.

```
role = discord.utils.get(Player.guild.roles, name="role")
await member.add_role(role)
```

I'm using `bot` not `client` and I am not using `ctx` instead I'm using `message` and I'm using `on_message()`. Whenever I run the code it gives me the error message

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'guild' for class 'str'
```

So how would I make `Player` a user id instead of a string. `Player` shows

```
@!8214498848170 etc
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the `Player`?

Comment: `Player` is a string holding a user-id `@!8214498848170 etc` and now I'm trying to use `Player` to find a user and give them a role in my discord server

Comment: Is `etc` in this string or by etc you mean that there is something more after the id?

Comment: `etc` is the user-id but i dont want to give my full id to the public

Comment: and what is the member? It would be much easier if you gave [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can just copy your code and get your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guild` object is only an attribute of a real `member`, not of a string, hence your error.
You can however parse your string to retrieve the user-id, and then get or fetch the member. Discord-IDs are 18 **or** 19 digits long. Using static string indexing for the length of the id should be avoided.

```
userID = int(Player[2:])
```

Fetch the member

```
member = await message.guild.fetch_member(userID)
```

And now you can assign the member a role

```
userID = int(Player[2:].split(" ")[0])
member = await message.guild.fetch_member(userID)
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="role")
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: When i run the code it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'`

Comment: I just realized that `8214498848170` is not a user ID. Where exactly does is it located in your `Player` string? Without knowing of what you `Player` string consists its impossible for me to correctly say how to extract the user-id from your example command. I'm now **guessing** that `Player` looks like this `@!8214498848170 <your-user-id> <etc>` and updating my answer

Comment: The full user id is `@!821449884817031238` after removing the `<` and `>`

Comment: It that all whats written in `Player`? Only `@!{user-id}`?

Comment: yes `Player` only consists of `@!821449884817031238`

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer to fit. It should now work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232807/discussion-between-hunter-and-itzflubby).